# Maintaining/avoiding having to import a .csv file with tens of millions of rows on a day-to-day basis in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, bigdata, python-import

I have a file (File_A) with greater than 40 million rows which I need to import into Python and compare certain aspects to another very large data file (File_B). One example: find rows in File_A whose 'ID' is not contained in the 'ID' Column of File_B.

These are by far the biggest data files I have ever worked with, and I am wondering if there is a mechanism to avoid having to read_csv every day when I log on (however they have my system set up, the kernel is usually timed out every day or so). I'm using chunksize to bring the file into a df in batches, but it still takes around half an hour.

Is there a way to avoid this rather cumbersome process whenever my kernel gets reset / the python file gets closed?

Additionally, any general recommendations on packages/concepts for importing, manipulating and comparing these super large datasets like these is much appreciated.

Comment: why not use a db? you could use even sqlite, which is portable

Comment: Instead of reading the entire file into a dataframe, use a Trie data structure to store the contents of the `ID` column. Lookups for a Trie are `O(n)` where `n` is the length of the `ID` so it is fast. The line number of the data within the file can be stored in the data structure to speed up access to individual lines. You can save the data structure as a Pickle file so you can quickly reload it if required later.